# create a list of separate dictionaries to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list in this format

```
a=[{'a':'123'},{'b':'name1'},{'c':'login'},{'a':'234'},{'b':'name2'},{'c':'Logout'}]
```

and I want to convert the above list to pandas dataframe in the below format

```
a     b     c
123 name1 login
234 name2 logout
```

Can anyone tell me how to convert?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create dictionary of lists by [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) and pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

for x in a:
    for k, v in x.items():
        d[k].append(v)

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print (df)
     a      b       c
0  123  name1   login
1  234  name2  Logout
```